# Getting error at while installing node in windows7

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, chocolatey

i am getting at the time while i install node and npm on my windows7 os. Can any body help me so that i can fixed my problem to move ahead.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhTS6.png)

Answer (score 1):

you did not specify how are you trying to install node.

you can head to [nodejs download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), download node installation and then install it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that as you tagged your question with 'chocolatey' that your issue is similar to this [one](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/2059)?

If that is the case the best port of call would be to raise an issue for the NodeJS team if you are having issues like this.

If this is a different issue, as [Mr said above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62242775/1241425), we really need more info.